# How to delete a [object BSON] collection from mongo console

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection on mongo and I wanted to copy all it's documents to another collection via the mongo console.

When I execute the command *show collections* I see this:

- MyCollection

Then I executed the command *db.MyCollection.copyTo(db.MyCollection2);*

The problem is it generated a bson object so now when I execute 'show collections' I see:

- MyCollection
- [object BSON]

I don't know how is that [object BSON] being stored nor even how to access to it.

I would like to know:

- 1) How to delete the [object BSON] object
- 2) How to properly duplicate the MyCollection into another MyCollection2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Read [`copyTo()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) again. **db.collection.copyTo(newCollection)** That `newCollection` means a "string" which is the "name of the new collection" not pointing to an "Object", so hence the error. The method is also deprecated due to it's use of `eval`, which is due for removal. So you really should be reading the documentation and using the alternate methods like it says. But you can simply correct by using the "string" for the name.

Comment: I have checked the documentation on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/

that is how I found the method, there it says:
"Copies all documents from collection into newCollection using server-side JavaScript. If newCollection does not exist, MongoDB creates it." 
I assume that is what I need. No alternate method mentioned there. Still stuck with the problem. :(

Comment: How are you still stuck? `db.MyCollection.copyTo('MyCollection2')`. I actually just told you that. Or were you do busy telling me you did read the documentation to actually read the response?

Comment: Fun fact. You can do this with any function in the Mongo shell ( or any JavaScript REPL for that matter. Type in the function without the brackets `()` ie. `db.MyCollection.copyTo`. This will print out the actual code that the fuction implements. You can clearly see ( if you then refer to the documentation of referenced operations contained ) that the argument is a "string".

Comment: Hi, yes that was exactly what happened, based on your comment, I read the documentation again, this time extensively, fearing that I has missed something, then I solved it by passing a string as parameter and later realize this was on your response. So I could continue working (Although I could not remove the previous [object BSON] generated).  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I was able to get ride of the `[object BSON]` collection by issuing this command:
`db.runCommand({drop: '[object BSON]'})`

I'm using mongodb version 3.2.17